# Get the path of the project in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm developing a package for logging in Node.js. I want to able to read the path of the project where my package is being used. That's because I want the user to be able to put a config file in the root of their project. I want to achieve something similar as the ESLint package being able to read the `.eslintrc` file.

Comment: `__dirname` is an environment variable that points to the CWD, or you can use `path.resolve()`

Comment: @mstephen19 — `__dirname` a variable, not an environment variable, and it points to the directory the module is not, not the CWD. `path.resolve()` will give you the CWD, but that isn't the same as the root directory of the project.

Comment: @Quentin They refer to it as an environment variable. Try to use `__dirname` in a module and check the error message.

But thank you for the info about where it points to :)

Comment: @mstephen19 — Who are "they"? I don't see the word environment in [the Node.js documentation for __dirname](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#__dirname).

Comment: I finally understand the question. @Steven Arias check out the `callsite` package. `callsite()[2].getFileName()` will point to the CWD.

Comment: eslint is typically used as a standalone program (e.g. I believe VS Code runs it as a subprocess rather than importing the eslint module into its own JS engine) and cares about the CWD. Your problem sounds more like you want to check paths based on the location of the JS module that is `require`ing or `import`ing your logging module. Can you clarify how you intend your code to be used (possibly with a simple example that includes information about your directory structure and how you see the logger being invoked)?

Comment: Here's one way to do it: https://github.com/yargs/yargs/blob/main/docs/advanced.md#rc-files

Answer (score 1):

> I want to able to read the path of the project where my package is being used

`process.argv[1]` will be the fully qualified path of the root script that was executed (perhaps without file extension).

So, you can take that fully qualified path and then get just the directory like this:

```
const rootdir = path.dirname(process.argv[1]);
```

As you asked, this is the directory where the root script that started the whole nodejs program is located.  That may or may not be where your particular module was loaded from.  Your module could be loaded from some other module which was itself loaded from the root script.

Also, this is not necessarily the same directory as the current working directory, `process.cwd()`.  If a path is passed to the root script, then the current working directory can literally be anything so it cannot be counted on to point at any specific module.

---

Note that good modularity will NOT have dependencies on specific parent modules or specific parent modules being located in certain places.  If your module needs to know where some resources are located, it should be able to find them in one of several ways:

1. In it's own directory (accessible via `__dirname` or `import.meta`).
2. In some configuration data passed into the module at initialization time.
3. In a location specified in either the environment or a config file in a known location.

You should generally not write a module that must have certain parent modules in known locations.  Somewhat by definition, that's not an easily shareable, reusable module if it can only be used by a specific other module that has a specific structure.